# Atom editor - different colored blocky background for dark themes

Tags: atom-editor

#### Description

This problem appears on Atom 1.32.1 under Ubuntu 18.04 in `atom --safe` mode. Enable a dark theme and start typing text, and the background alters between dark black, and dark grey, in large blocky chunks. Looks like an Atari 2600 game.

**Expected behavior:** One consistent background.

**Actual behavior:** See this picture. How do I escape this bug?

[image]
<sub>(source: [discourse-cdn-sjc1.com](https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/business6/uploads/github_atom/optimized/3X/6/a/6aa7fd98ccc53af471b5dd4a2fb61423f5858262_1_690x258.png))</sub>

Comment: Did you find any solution? Have the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 and Atom 1.34.

Comment: Nope. Still waiting.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Preferences` -> `Core tab` -> `Color Profile` -> change to `Use sRGB`
[image: Check this image]